# beaglebone ai-64 board and RFID RC-522 device connection and serial communication questions

Tags: uart, spi

The card tag detection and UID information of the RFID RC522 module is transmitted to the beaglebone ai-64 board through SPI communication, and this information is to be transmitted from the board to the PC through UART communication.

At this time, referring to the URL below, the dts file was changed to a dtbo file and the dto setting was flashed on the board.
URL : https://github.com/beagleboard/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees/blob/v5.10.x-ti-unified/pinmux/bbai64.dts

The main source code at that time is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <termios.h>      // Add UART-related header files

#define SPI_DEVICE "/dev/spidev1.0"  // SPI device path
#define UART_DEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"     // UART device path
#define SS_PIN 17                   // SPI SS (Chip Select) pin number
#define RST_PIN 9                   // RST pin number
#define MISO_PIN 21
#define MOSI_PIN 18
#define SCK_PIN 26

// the device tree source needs to be modified first as follow.
// BONE_PIN(P9_17, spi, P9_17A(PIN_OUTPUT, 4), P9_17B(PIN_INPUT, 7));  // spi6_cs0
// BONE_PIN(P9_18, spi, P9_18A(PIN_OUTPUT, 4), P9_18B(PIN_INPUT, 7));  // spi6_d1
// BONE_PIN(P9_21, spi, P9_21A(PIN_OUTPUT, 4), P9_21B(PIN_INPUT, 7));  // spi6_d0
// BONE_PIN(P9_26, spi, P9_26A(PIN_OUTPUT, 0), P9_26B(PIN_INPUT, 7));  // spi1_clk

#define MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI 0x09
#define MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K 0x04
#define MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_4K 0x02

int spi_fd;
int gpio_fd;
int uart_fd;  

// MFRC522 initialization
void MFRC522Init() { 
    // RST pin initialization
    char rst_pin_path[64];
    snprintf(rst_pin_path, sizeof(rst_pin_path), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", RST_PIN);
    int rst_pin_fd = open(rst_pin_path, O_WRONLY);
    if (rst_pin_fd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open RST pin\n");
        return;
    }
    write(rst_pin_fd, "0", 1);
    usleep(500000);
    write(rst_pin_fd, "1", 1); 
    usleep(500000);
    close(rst_pin_fd);
}

// initialize SPI communication
int SpiInit() {
    spi_fd = open("SPI_DEVICE", O_RDWR);

    // SPI mode setting
    uint8_t mode = SPI_MODE_0;

    // Set maximum baud rate (1MHz)
    uint32_t speed = 1000000;
    return 0;
}

// Sending and receiving SPI data
int SpiTransfer(uint8_t* tx_data, uint8_t* rx_data, int len) {
    struct spi_ioc_transfer spi_transfer = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx_data, 
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx_data, 
        .len = len,                      
        .delay_usecs = 0,
        .speed_hz = 0,
        .bits_per_word = 8,
    };
    if (ioctl(spi_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &spi_transfer) < 0) {
        printf("SPI transfer error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Check if the card exists
int PICC_IsNewCardPresent() {
    uint8_t tx_data[] = {0x02, 0x00};       // MFRC522 default data packet
    uint8_t rx_data[sizeof(tx_data)];
    memset(rx_data, 0, sizeof(rx_data));
    if (SpiTransfer(tx_data, rx_data, sizeof(tx_data)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to transfer data\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return rx_data[1];
}

// Read card UID information
int PICC_ReadCardSerial(uint8_t* uid) {
    uint8_t tx_data[] = {0x0B, 0x00};
    uint8_t rx_data[sizeof(tx_data)];
    memset(rx_data, 0, sizeof(rx_data));
    if (SpiTransfer(tx_data, rx_data, sizeof(tx_data)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to transfer data\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memcpy(uid, &rx_data[1], 4);
    return 0;
}

// Get card type
uint8_t PICC_GetType(uint8_t sak) { //  select Acknowledge, Returns a 7-bit value representing card type information
    return sak & 0x7F;
}

// Get card type name
const char* PICC_GetTypeName(uint8_t piccType) {
    switch (piccType) {
        case MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI:
            return "MIFARE Mini";
        case MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K:
            return "MIFARE 1K";
        case MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_4K:
            return "MIFARE 4K";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}

// Convert to hexadecimal and output
void printHex(uint8_t* data, uint8_t length) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%02X", data[i]);
    }
}

// UART initialization
int UartInit() {
    uart_fd = open(UART_DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (uart_fd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open UART\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart_fd, &options);   // import current setting

    // Set baud rate (9600 bps)
    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

    // Set data bit, parity bit, stop bit
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // Set control options
    // options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    options.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tcsetattr(uart_fd, TCSANOW, &options);   // apply new settings to uart_fd

    return 0;
}

// Convert data to UART (write)
void WriteUidUart(const char* data) {
    write(uart_fd, data, strlen(data));
}

int main() {
    // MFRC522 initialization
    MFRC522Init();

    // SPI communication initialization
    if (SpiInit() != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // UART communication initialization
    if (UartInit() != 0) {
        return -1;
    }


    uint8_t nuidPICC[4] = {0};  // Save old card UID

    while (1) {
        // If the card is recognized, move on to the next, otherwise do not run any further.
        if (!PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
            continue;

        // If the ID has been read, it goes to the next one, otherwise it doesn't run any further.
        if (!PICC_ReadCardSerial(nuidPICC))
            continue;

        printf("PICC type: ");

        // Read the type of card
        uint8_t piccType = PICC_GetType(nuidPICC[0]);

        // output to monitor
        printf("%s\n", PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

        // Check if it is a MIFARE method and return otherwise
        if (piccType != MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI &&
            piccType != MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K &&
            piccType != MFRC522_PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_4K) {
            printf("Your tag is not of type MIFARE Classic.\n");
            continue;
        }

        // If it is different from the RF card recognized just before...
        if (nuidPICC[0] != nuidPICC[0] ||
            nuidPICC[1] != nuidPICC[1] ||
            nuidPICC[2] != nuidPICC[2] ||
            nuidPICC[3] != nuidPICC[3]) {
            printf("A new card has been detected.\n");

            // save ID
            memcpy(nuidPICC, nuidPICC, sizeof(nuidPICC));

            // output to monitor
            printf("The NUID tag is:\n");
            printf("In hex: ");

            // Convert to hexadecimal and output
            printHex(nuidPICC, sizeof(nuidPICC));
            printf("\n");

            // Send card information to PC via UART
            char uartData[9];
            snprintf(uartData, sizeof(uartData), "%02X%02X%02X%02X\n", nuidPICC[0], nuidPICC[1], nuidPICC[2], nuidPICC[3]);
            WriteUidUart(uartData);
        }

        // PICC exit
        usleep(100000);
    }

    close(spi_fd);
    close(uart_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

However, since the beaglebone ai-64 board does not support gpio pins from pins P9_9, an error will occur if you write the following code like the code above.

```
snprintf(rst_pin_path, sizeof(rst_pin_path), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", RST_PIN);
```

Therefore, I am trying to change the part that initializes the MFRC522, and I would like to receive ideas or feedback on this part.